Problem with uploading multiple Image files to the server using Multer and save it to DB
I am trying to uploading multiple images to the server, but I am unable to do this. My code file is below, anyone's help would be appreciated.
Here I am taking images file input and storing it into an images array, but when making the post request to the backend, Images is been uploaded using "uploadFileHandler" but not saving to MongoDB when I use "handleSubmit"
I understand this problem, but unable to find the solution of this.
ProductList.jsx

import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  useCreateProductMutation,
  useUploadProductImageMutation,
} from "../../redux/api/productApiSlice";
import { useFetchCategoriesQuery } from "../../redux/api/categoryApiSlice";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
// import AdminMenu from "./AdminMenu";

const ProductList = () => {
  // const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
  const [stock, setStock] = useState(0);
  // const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null);
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [uploadProductImage] = useUploadProductImageMutation();
  const [createProduct] = useCreateProductMutation();
  const { data: categories } = useFetchCategoriesQuery();

  const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const uploadedImages = e.target.files;

    for (const image of uploadedImages) {
      formData.append("images", image);
    }

    try {
      const res = await uploadProductImage(formData).unwrap();
      toast.success(res.message);
      setImages(uploadedImages);
      setImageUrls(res.imageUrls);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error?.data?.message || error.data);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const productData = new FormData();
      productData.append("name", name);
      productData.append("description", description);
      productData.append("price", price);
      productData.append("brand", brand);
      productData.append("category", category);
      productData.append("quantity", quantity);
      productData.append("countInStock", stock);
      for (const image of images) {
        productData.append("images", image);
      }

      const { data } = await createProduct(productData);

      if (data.error) {
        toast.error("Product create failed. Try Again.");
      } else {
        toast.success(data.message);
        navigate("/admin/allproductslist");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      toast.error("Product create failed. Try Again.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container xl:mx-[9rem] sm:mx-[0]">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
        <div className="md:w-3/4 p-3">
          <div className="h-12 text-black text-2xl">
            <span className="text-3xl font-bold">Create Product</span>

            {/* <AdminMenu /> */}
            <div className="mt-[3rem]">
              {imageUrls.length > 0 &&
                imageUrls.map((url, index) => (
                  <div key={index} className="inline-flex m-2">
                    <img
                      src={url}
                      alt={`product ${index + 1}`}
                      className="mx-auto max-h-[200px]"
                    />
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label className="border text-black px-4 block w-full text-center rounded-lg cursor-pointer font-bold py-11">
                {!images.length > 0 ? "Upload Images" : "Choose Images"}

                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="images"
                  accept="image/"
                  multiple
                  onChange={uploadFileHandler}
                  className={!images.length ? "hidden" : "text-black"}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="p-3">
              <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                <div className="one">
                  <label className="text-black" htmlFor="name">
                    Name{" "}
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="p-4 mb-3 w-[30rem] border rounded-lg bg-white text-black"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="two ml-0 lg:ml-2">
                  <label className="text-black" htmlFor="name block">
                    Price{" "}
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="p-4 mb-3 w-[30rem] border rounded-lg bg-white text-black "
                    value={price}
                    onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                <div className="one">
                  <label className="text-black" htmlFor="name block">
                    Quantity{" "}
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    className="p-4 mb-3 w-[30rem] border rounded-lg bg-white text-black"
                    value={quantity}
                    onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="two ml-0 lg:ml-2">
                  <label className="text-black" htmlFor="name block">
                    Brand{" "}
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="p-4 mb-3 w-[30rem] border rounded-lg bg-white text-black"
                    value={brand}
                    onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <label htmlFor="" className="my-5 text-black">
                Description
              </label>
              <textarea
                type="text"
                className="p-2 mb-3 bg-white border rounded-lg w-[95%] text-black"
                value={description}
                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
              ></textarea>

              <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:justify-between">
                <div className="mb-4 md:mb-0">
                  {" "}
                  {/* Margin bottom, no margin on md */}
                  <label className="text-black" htmlFor="name block">
                    Count In Stock
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    className="p-4 border w-[30rem] rounded-lg bg-white text-black"
                    value={stock}
                    onChange={(e) => setStock(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="ml-0 md:ml-4">
                  {" "}
                  {/* Margin left 0, margin left 4 on md */}
                  <label className="text-black" htmlFor="name block">
                    Category
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <select
                    className="p-4 w-[30rem] border rounded-lg bg-white text-black"
                    value={category}
                    onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
                  >
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                    {categories?.map((c) => (
                      <option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                        {c.name}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                className="text-white py-4 px-10 mt-5 rounded-lg text-lg font-bold bg-pink-600 hover:bg-pink-700"
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;


productApiSlice.js

import {apiSlice} from "./apiSlice"
import { PRODUCT_URL, UPLOAD_URL } from "../constants"

export const productApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        createProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (productData) => ({
                url: `${PRODUCT_URL}`,
                method: "POST",
                body: productData,
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["Product"],
        }),

        updateProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: ({ productId, formData }) => ({
                url: `${PRODUCT_URL}/${productId}`,
                method: "PUT",  
                body: formData,
            })
        }),

        deleteProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (productId) => ({
                url: `${PRODUCT_URL}/${productId}`,
                method: "DELETE",
            }),
            providesTags: ["Product"],
        }),

        getProducts: builder.query({
            query: ({keyword}) =>  ({
                url: `${PRODUCT_URL}`,
                params: { keyword },
            }),
            keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
            providesTags: ["Product"],
        }),

        allProducts: builder.query({
            query: () => `${PRODUCT_URL}/allproducts`,
        }),

        getNewProducts: builder.query({
            query: () => `${PRODUCT_URL}/new`,
            keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
        }),

        getTopProducts: builder.query({
            query: () => `${PRODUCT_URL}/top`,
            keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
        }),

        getProductById: builder.query({
            query: (productId) => ({
                url: `${PRODUCT_URL}/${productId}`,
                providestags: (result, error, productId) => [
                    {type: "Product", id: productId},
                ],
            }),
        }),

        getProductDetails: builder.query({
            query: (productId) => ({
              url: `${PRODUCT_URL}/${productId}`,
            }),
            keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
        }),

        getFilteredProducts: builder.query({
          query: ({ checked, radio }) => ({
            url: `${PRODUCT_URL}/filtered-products`,
            method: "POST",
            body: { checked, radio },
          }),
        }),

        uploadProductImage: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
              url: `${UPLOAD_URL}`,
              method: "POST",
              body: data,
            }),
        }),

        createReview: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
              url: `${PRODUCT_URL}/${data.productId}/reviews`,
              method: "POST",
              body: data,
            }),
        }),
    }),
})

export const {
    useCreateProductMutation,
    useGetProductsQuery,
    useAllProductsQuery,
    useGetTopProductsQuery,
    useGetNewProductsQuery,
    useUpdateProductMutation,
    useDeleteProductMutation,
    useGetFilteredProductsQuery,
    useGetProductByIdQuery,
    useGetProductDetailsQuery,
    useUploadProductImageMutation,
    useCreateReviewMutation,
} = productApiSlice

productModel.js


import mongoose from "mongoose";
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    rating: {type: Number, required: true},
    comment: {type: String, required: true},
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User",
    }
}, {timestamps: true});

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    images: [{ type: String }],
    brand: {type: String, required: true},
    color: {type: [String]},
    size: {type: [String]},
    quantity: {type: Number, required: true},
    category: {type: ObjectId, ref: "Category", required: true},
    subcategories: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Subcategory"}],
    reviews: [reviewSchema],
    rating: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
    numReviews: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
    price: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
    countInStock: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
}, { timestamps: true });

export default mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

productController.js


import asyncHandler from "../middlewares/asyncHandler.js"
import Product from '../models/productModel.js'

const addProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, description, price, category, quantity, brand, images } = req.fields;

        console.log(name)
        console.log(description)
        console.log(price)
        console.log(category)
        console.log(quantity)
        console.log(brand)
        console.log(images)
        // Validation
        switch (true) {
            case !name:
                return res.json({ error: "Name is required!" });
            case !description:
                return res.json({ error: "Description is required!" });
            case !price:
                return res.json({ error: "Price is required!" });
            case !category:
                return res.json({ error: "Category is required!" });
            case !quantity:
                return res.json({ error: "Quantity is required!" });
            case !brand:
                return res.json({ error: "Brand is required!" }); 
            // case !images:
            //     return res.json({ error: "Images is required!" });         
        }
        const product = new Product({ ...req.fields })
        await product.save()
        res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json(error);
    }
});

const updateProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, description, price, category, quantity, brand, images } = req.fields;
        
        console.log(name)
        console.log(description)
        console.log(price)
        console.log(category)
        console.log(quantity)
        console.log(brand)
        // Validation
        switch (true) {
            case !name:
                return res.json({ error: "Name is required!" });
            case !description:
                return res.json({ error: "Description is required!" });
            case !price:
                return res.json({ error: "Price is required!" });
            case !category:
                return res.json({ error: "Category is required!" });
            case !quantity:
                return res.json({ error: "Quantity is required!" });
            case !brand:
                return res.json({ error: "Brand is required!" });         
        }
        const newProduct = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id, 
            { ...req.fields }, 
            {new: true}
        )
        await newProduct.save()
        res.status(201).json(newProduct);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json(error);
    }
})

const deleteProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Product.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
        res.status(200).json(product);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json(error);
    }
})

// Define an asynchronous handler for fetching products
const fetchProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Define the number of products per page
        const pageSize = 6;
        
        // Extract the keyword from the request query if it exists, otherwise initialize an empty object
        const keyword = req.query.keyword 
            ? { name: { $regex: req.query.keyword, $options: "i" } }
            : {};
        
        // Get the count of products matching the keyword criteria
        const count = await Product.countDocuments({ ...keyword });

        // Fetch products based on the keyword criteria and limit the result to the pageSize
        const products = await Product.find({ ...keyword }).limit(pageSize);

        // Send a JSON response with the fetched products, current page number, total pages, and a flag to indicate if there are more products
        res.json({
            products,
            page: 1,
            pages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize),
            hasMore: false
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any errors that occurred during the process
        console.log(error);
        
        // Return a 404 status with an error message if products are not found
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Product not found" });
    }
})

const fetchProductById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)

        if (product) {
            return res.json(product);
        } else {
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error("Product not found");
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Product not found" });
    }
})

// Define an asynchronous handler for fetching all products
const fetchAllProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Fetch all products from the database
        const products = await Product.find({})
            .populate("category")  // Populate the 'category' field for each product with the actual category document
            .limit(12)  // Limit the number of products to be fetched to 12
            .sort({ createAt: -1 });  // Sort the products in descending order based on the 'createAt' field

        // Return a JSON response with the fetched products and a 200 status code
        return res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any errors that occurred during the process
        console.log(error);
        
        // Return a 404 status with an error message if products are not found
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Product not found" });
    }
})

// Define an asynchronous handler for adding a product review
const addProductReview = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Destructure 'rating' and 'comment' from the request body
        const { rating, comment } = req.body;

        // Find the product by ID from the database
        const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

        // Check if the product exists
        if (product) {
            // Check if the user has already reviewed the product
            const alreadyReviewed = product.reviews.find((r) => r.user.toString() === req.user._id.toString());

            if (alreadyReviewed) {
                // If product is already reviewed by the user, send a 404 status and throw an error
                res.status(404);
                throw new Error("Product already reviewed");
            }

            // Create a new review object
            const review = {
                name: req.user.username,
                rating: Number(rating),
                comment,
                user: req.user._id
            };

            // Add the new review to the product's reviews array
            product.reviews.push(review);
            product.numReviews = product.reviews.length;

            // Calculate the average rating for the product
            product.rating = product.reviews.reduce((acc, item) => item.rating + acc, 0) / product.reviews.length;

            // Save the updated product with the new review
            await product.save();

            // Return a success response with a 201 status (Created) and a message
            res.status(201).json({ message: "Review added" });
        } else {
            // If the product is not found, send a 404 status and throw an error
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error("Product not found");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any errors that occurred during the process
        console.error(error);
        
        // Return a 400 status (Bad Request) and the error message in the response
        return res.status(400).json(error.message);
    }
});

const fetchTopProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.find({}).sort({rating: -1}).limit(4)
        res.json(products)        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(400).json(error.message);
    }
})

const fetchNewProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(5)
        res.json(products)        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(400).json(error.message);
    }
})

// Define an asynchronous handler for filtering products based on certain criteria
const filterProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Destructure 'checked' and 'radio' arrays from the request body
        const { checked, radio } = req.body;

        // Initialize an empty object for filtering arguments
        let args = {};

        // Check if 'checked' array has elements, if so, add 'category' to the filter arguments
        if (checked.length > 0) args.category = checked;

        // Check if 'radio' array has elements, if so, add price range filter to the arguments
        if (radio.length) args.price = { $gte: radio[0], $lte: radio[1] };

        // Query the database to find products that match the filter arguments
        const products = await Product.find(args);

        // Respond with the filtered products in JSON format
        res.json(products);
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any errors that occurred during the process
        console.error(error);
        
        // Return a 500 status (Internal Server Error) and an error message in the response
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Server Error" });
    }
});

export { 
    addProduct,
    updateProduct,
    deleteProduct,
    fetchProducts,
    fetchProductById,
    fetchAllProducts,
    addProductReview,
    fetchTopProducts,
    fetchNewProducts,
    filterProducts,
}

productRoute.js


import express from "express";
import formidable from "express-formidable";
import {
  addProduct,
  updateProduct,
  deleteProduct,
  fetchProducts,
  fetchProductById,
  fetchAllProducts,
  addProductReview,
  fetchTopProducts,
  fetchNewProducts,
  filterProducts,
} from "../controllers/productController.js";
import {
  authenticate,
  authorizedAdmin,
} from "../middlewares/authMiddleware.js";
import checkId from "../middlewares/checkId.js";

const router = express.Router();

router
  .route("/")
  .post(authenticate, authorizedAdmin, formidable(), addProduct)
  .get(fetchProducts);

router.route("/allProducts").get(fetchAllProducts);

router.route("/top").get(fetchTopProducts);

router.route("/new").get(fetchNewProducts);

router.route("/:id/reviews").post(authenticate, checkId, addProductReview);

router
  .route("/:id")
  .put(authenticate, authorizedAdmin, formidable(), updateProduct)
  .delete(authenticate, authorizedAdmin, deleteProduct)
  .get(fetchProductById);

router.route("/filtered-products").post(filterProducts);

export default router;

uploadRoute.js


import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";

const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },

  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const extname = path.extname(file.originalname);
    const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    const uniqueFilename = `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}-${randomString}${extname}`;
    cb(null, uniqueFilename);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const filetypes = /jpe?g|png|webp/;
  const mimetypes = /image\/jpe?g|image\/png|image\/webp/;

  const extname = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
  const mimetype = file.mimetype;

  if (filetypes.test(extname) && mimetypes.test(mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("Images only"), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter });

const uploadMultipleImages = upload.array("images", 10); // 10 is the maximum number of files

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  uploadMultipleImages(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: err.message
      });
    } else if (req.files && req.files.length > 0) {
      const imageUrls = req.files.map((file) => `/${file.path}`);
      return res.status(200).send({
        message: "Images uploaded successfully",
        imageUrls: imageUrls
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: "No images provided"
      });
    }
  });
});

export default router;


